# NDK version is UNKNOWN

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk

После обновления AndroidStudio стала появляться эта ошибка, и не получается начать проект. В чём может быть проблема?

```
NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK 
version is UNKNOWN
```

При этом я скачал NDK и указал путь
**local.properties**

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Android\\AndroidSdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Android\\AndroidSdk
```

**build**

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "shihzaman.com.my"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    }
```

**build проекта**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй другую версию Gradle-плагина, например 3.5.0, так же проверь правильно ли указана версия Gradle в Project Structure:

| Версия плагина | Версия Gradle |
| --- | --- |
| 3.2.0 — 3.2.1 | 4.6+ |
| 3.3.0 — 3.3.3 | 4.10.1+ |
| 3.4.0 — 3.4.3 | 5.1.1+ |
| 3.5.0+ | 5.4.1+ |

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin